# How to check if a record was updating using Zend Framework's 2 Sql Adapter Class

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm trying to test to see if an update query was successful with Zend Framework 2. I'm using the `getAdapter()->query()` methods but I'm unsure of how to actually test to see if anything was returned or if it actually executed. I know it is executing (as I can see the update working via mysql workbench) but I'm not sure on how to actually count or verify. Here is the code I have in place (which I know is wrong but I don't know what else to do):

```
 $update = $this->update->table('stores')
                ->set(array('number_of_items' => $number))->where(array('store_name' => $this->store_name));

 $query = $this->sql->getAdapter()->query($this->sql->buildSqlString($update), Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);

 if ($query->count() > 0) {
     // insert the items into the items table
    $insert = $this->insert->into('items')
        ->columns(array('store_id', 'price', 'description'))
        ->values(array($row['store_id'], $price, $item_desc));

    $query = $this->sql->getAdapter()->query(
        $this->sql->buildSqlString($insert),
        Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE
    );

    if ($query->count() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new \Exception("Error adding your item to the items table, please try again.");
    }
} else {
    // this is the exception being thrown
    throw new \Exception("An error occurred while adding your item(s) to the store, please try again");
}
```

Now I know most likely `count()` will only work on select queries but I am unsure of how to test to see if the update and insert were successful.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if update and insert were successful.
As per your code

```
  try {
      $affetedRows = $this->insert->into('items')
                    ->columns(array('store_id', 'price', 'description'))
                    ->values(array($row['store_id'], $price, $item_desc));
            }catch (\Exception $e) {
                var_dump($e->getMessage());exit; // see if any exaption Or error in query
            }
    }
```

> var_dump($affetedRows )  // it will return number of affected rows.

Same for `delete` and `update`, after successfull execution `delete` and `update`are also returns number of affected rows.

so if there is successfull exceution, you can check success of your query.

Thanks.